# Create a new table from a report filter

Tags: excel, powerbi, xlsx

I have an xlsx file that contain a investment flow. Each column is a diferente fund e the line the date, the information is how much each fund has in that date. I would like to crete a new table that will return only a line, date, selected by a filter in report. The object is take that information e merge with another table that I can agreggate the funds by benchmark, manager or legal classification. Theres anyway that I can do this with power BI?

EDIT 1:
I don't know how to share datasheets here, I created a google docs. The first sheet is how much in each fund. The second is the classification of each fund.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZzveK6ogk-QPPidAeGdQBVwADa_qwqTf19B5qt6CpuM/edit?usp=sharing

In the middle line, the table, barplot and piechart are the values of each fund aggregated by its attributes: legal, manager and benchmark. I did with the last line of the flow and merged with the second sheet. But I want the value of the line of the last day selected in the date filter (top/left of the pic).
[image]

I hope it's the enough, but I can give more information if needed!

EDIT2: 
I know how to create a measure of data selected, but I don't know how to relate that to the second sheet.

Comment: As for my understanding, You can't create a table dynamically with user-selected input from the report through visual.

Comment: New table is not possilble. Functionality is, you will need to give much more detail on data and outcome you want so we can help you..

Comment: I gave more detail in the edit, if u need more, talk, pls!